# How to send notification to registered users of same application in android application

Tags: java, android

hi everyone i'm beginner to the android. I'm developing a android application for a **website**, in which i need to **update the notifications**. But i don't know how the notifications will be reached to the users. Can any one please explain how the **functionality** will goes on and how i can send the notifications to the users.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you gone through cloud messaging? try this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: You can use Push Notifications to send the Notifications to Android. The best way would be, using Firebase to send them. Please check [this](https://www.codementor.io/android/tutorial/send-push-notifications-to-android-with-firebase)

Comment: Thanks a lot this will be useful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use google cloud messaging (GCM) for beginner it is easy to set up.

Follow this [LINK](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client)

Once you are done with the Set Up then follow [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/downstream) for sending notification from server to client.

And this [link](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/upstream) for client request to application.

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you go through the mentioned link, its an open source project which has implementation for notification handling you are looking after.
Putting it here so that anyone else can also leverage.

https://www.openhub.net/p/google-cloud-messaging--titanium-